# Azure Service IMessageSender with DI

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, service, servicebus

I am using .net core project .

I implemented DI like  :

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMessageSender>(x => new 
    MessageSender(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ServiceBusConnection"),"queueName"));
var serviceprovider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();

ServiceBusUtils.Configure(serviceprovider.GetService<IMessageSender>());
```

Also, I have a Utility class :

```
public static class ServiceBusUtils
{
  
    private static IMessageSender _messageSender;

  
    public static void Configure(IMessageSender messageSender)
    {
        _messageSender = messageSender;
    }

    
    public static async Task<bool> SendMessage(ExecuteMessage<Message> message ,string queueName,string Id)
    {
       

        var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Message)))
        {
            SessionId = Id,
        };

        await _messageSender.SendAsync(message);

        return true;
    }
}
```

But I cannot set the `queuename` with the parameter.

I want to use implementation like

```
ServiceBusUtils.SendMessage(message,"quename");
```

Comment: Where are you configuring your ServiceBusUtils.Configure(serviceprovider.GetService());?

Comment: In startup class I will configure with connection string and queue name but I want to set multiple queue name(dynamic)

Comment: Any reason for using ServiceBusUtils as a static class?

Comment: If it is possible, yes but I would like to see other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register named clients for using with multiple queue names. The following code will give you an idea.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var queueNames = new string[] { "q1", "q2" };
    var queueFactory = new Dictionary<string, IMessageSender>();
            
    foreach (var queueName in queueNames)
    {
        queueFactory.Add(queueName, new MessageSender(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ServiceBusConnection"),queueName));
    }

    services.AddSingleton(queueFactory);
    services.AddSingleton<IServiceBus,ServiceBus>();
}


public interface IServiceBus
{
    public Task SendMessage(string message, string queue);
}


public class ServiceBus : IServiceBus
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, IMessageSender> _queueFactory;

    public ServiceBus(Dictionary<string, IMessageSender> queueFactory)
    {
        _queueFactory = queueFactory;
    }
    public async Task SendMessage(string message, string queue)
    {
        var messageSender = _queueFactory[queue];
        await messageSender.SendAysnc(message);
    }
}
```

You can pass the queue name to your send message method. This will resolve your MessageSender instance for the named queue.

```
_serviceBus.SendMessage("message","q1");
```